# Print Strings with java PrintWriter: Concatatenate or loop?

Tags: java, string, printing, output, concatenation

Suppose I want to print in java many strings like `"Hello" + var1 + "|" + var2` using `PrintWriter`.

My first option is using something like:

```
Output.print("Hello" + var1 + "|" + var2);
```

where `Output` is a `PrintWriter` instance. In this case Java has to concatenate all the items (some might need to be converted to `String`), and then passes a `String` parameter to write.

Maybe it would be more efficient something like this:

```
void PrintMsg(PrintWriter Output, String... Msg) {
    for(String M : Msg) Output.write(M);  
}
```

In this case I would call `PrintMsg(Output, "Hello", var1, "|", var2);`. There is no concatenation overhead, but only works for `String` parameters. If `var1`, `var2` are not `String` I would have to call:

```
PrintMsg(Output, "Hello", var1.toString(), "|", var2.toString());
```

or rewrite `PrintMsg` like this:

```
void PrintMsg(PrintWriter Output, Object... Msg) {
    for(Object M : Msg) Output.write(M.toString());  
}
```

I would like to know your opinions about how is the best way for doing this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you really have a lot of concatenation to perform, I may suggest you to use a `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The loop is almost certainly *slightly* better since doing the string concatenation is extra work.
2. It's extra work, but very little if we're just talking about the kind of thing in your question - it's just a few strings. You're worrying too much about a very small performance issue before actually observing it. You can worry if you start concatenating in a loop with *at least* 100 iterations. Premature optimisation is the root of all evil. On that note, the ideal way to answer this question is to write a program to measure the time taken. It's very easy to do.
3. `M.toString()` will throw an exception if `M == null`. Always remember to ask yourself what happens when something is `null`. You may *want* to throw an exception, but I think that's a bit messy in this case. Assuming you want to convert `null` to the string `"null"`, use `String.valueOf(M)`.
4. Java naming convention for methods and variables is `camelCase`, starting with a lowercase letter, so `printMsg`, `output`, `m`, `msg`.
5. Consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of question since it's specifically tailored for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be more efficient since there is a loop. In terms of execution it may be actually worse as it adds instructions for loop control which direct print has not.